# Rails g migration - not working in engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails (4.2) engine for a gem I'm writing.
Running: `rails g migration Anything` just gives the command help info

```
  Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]
```

What am I missing from my gem/engine to run rails generators?

**Update:** I didn't create a namespaced engine. It works fine in my other engines so I must have done something different in this..

Comment: Are you in your rails directory?

Comment: In the gem project directory yes

Comment: @rigyt try the command in project dir not in engine dir